# TabList in html not accessible

Tags: html

I'm using Accessibility Insights for Web to check a website accessibility errors.
There are two errors that i don't know how to solve.
First error:

**Path:** `div[ng-repeat="filter in c.filtersList"][ng-switch="filter.type"][ng-if="filter.active"]:nth-child(3) > .ng-scope[ng-switch-when="ACCORDION"] > uib-accordion > .panel-group[role="tablist"][ng-transclude=""]`

**Snippet:** `<div role="tablist" class="panel-group" ng-transclude="">`

**Related paths:** `#accordiongroup-2021-518-panel`

**How to fix:** *Fix ONE of the following:
Element has children which are not allowed (see Related paths)
Element has no aria-busy="true" attribute*

Second error:

**Path:** `#accordiongroup-2021-518-tab`

**Snippet:** `<div role="tab" id="accordiongroup-2021-518-tab" aria-selected="true" class="panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)">`

**Related paths:** `a[aria-controls="accordiongroup-2021-518-panel"]`

**How to fix:** *Fix the following:
Element has focusable descendants*

This is the source code of the html: https://controlc.com/57a10306

Can you help me?
I tried to modify the tabindex, roles and aria labels but the problem was not solved. could you give me a hand? Please :/

Answer (score 0):

Add an aria-busy="true" attribute to the div element with role="tablist". This indicates that the tablist is currently being loaded,

If there are any child elements within the div with role="tablist", make sure they have role="tab" and are associated with their corresponding panels using aria-controls.

Second error:

Make sure that the div element with role="tab" and aria-selected="true" does not have any focusable descendants

If there are any focusable descendants, consider wrapping them in a container with aria-hidden="true" to prevent them from being included in the tabbing order.

```
<div role="tablist" class="panel-group" ng-transclude="" aria-busy="true">
  <div role="tab" id="accordiongroup-2021-518-tab" aria-selected="true" class="panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)" aria-controls="accordiongroup-2021-518-panel">
    <!-- Add any content for the tab here -->
  </div>
</div>
```